# solve the equation $uu'+2e^u-t+e^ut=0$, $u(0)=1$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the equation, $uu'+2e^u-t+e^ut=0$, with $u(0)=1$.
This problem is giving me trouble because I don't know how to get the equation into the form of $dy/dx=g(x)f(y)$.

Comment: Doesn't u' = du/dt?

Comment: I think so, but I'm at a loss as to what to do after that.